# Excel freez pane and invisible gridlines settings are not saved

Tags: excel

I have an excel file in which I want to freez the view to cell D5 and I want the grid lines to be invisible. Getting this done works fine, however, these settings get lost sporadically after saving and re-opening the file. The file is on a server and four people work on it. I trust them when they tell me that they did not change it back. Could some local setting do this automatically?

Comment: I have a new idea what the source of the problem could be. Some of the people open more than one window with the file. It seems that the seetings are saved with the window and new windows are initialized with grid and without freez pane. If the file is then saved with the new window open, all settings are lost.

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot save it, maybe you can run some code to set your settings every time you open the file.

The following code will show you how to Run a Macro Automatically.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
    MsgBox "Hi dude! your settings were applied"
End Sub
```

That will eliminate the grid lines everytime you open the workbook. 
I don't know what you mean by freezing D5 cell, but can use the macro recorder to get the code of what you record to then use it in your procedures.
You should have your button "record macro" (mine is in spanish "Grabar macro")

[image]

For the code to execute when the workbook opens you should name the procedureas told (Private Sub Workbook_Open()) and paste it in the "ThisWorkbook" module.

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the good idea. Sadly in this case I am not allowed to do that. We have some safety restrictions and with files shared on a wide basis I am not allowed to use .xlsm files.

Comment: If you cannot do it from the file itself then you can do a python script to open the file and open the file from your machine according to your desired settings. Other suggestion is to investigate why the settings are not saved in the file, so check the user permissions in the server that hosts the file and in the local machines to ensure that the user is allow to modifiy the file. In left click / properties / safety you can set the configuration of the privileges of each of the users. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the view seetings are saved with the window and new windows are initialized with grid and without freez pane. If the file is then saved with the new window open, all settings are lost (i.e. set to default).